# Using Debian Stretch to build 5.15.x kernel with zstd compression fails with incorrect parameters

Tags: debian, linux-kernel, kernel-modules, zstd

I had to move from Jessie to Stretch as kernel 5.15.49 requires gcc 5.x version (Jessie had 4.9 version Stretch 6.x).   I decided to try the ZSTD module compression option in 5.15.x.  I ensured to `apt-get install zstd` beforehand.

Using `make bindeb-pkg` it gets all the way past compiling and signing the modules but then errors out and you can see on the screen the zstd output saying `incorrect parameters` then giving a sample of what the parameters should be.  So clearly it's executing the compressor but it doesn't like whatever parameters kbuild is sending it?

Is this a known issue? Is there an easy fix for this?

TIA!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debian Stretch has `zstd` version 1.1.2, which lacks support for the `-T0` option which the kernel uses (it instructs `zstd` to use all available cores).

`-T0` can be dropped without adversely affecting the build (other than the time taken to compress the modules); edit `scripts/Makefile.modinst` and remove `-T0` from `cmd_zstd`.

Note that Debian Stretch is about to drop out of long-term support (on June 30); if you want to continue using it, you should consider [Extended LTS](https://deb.freexian.com/extended-lts/).